# Oracle client client 12c 32 & 64 bits failling to install on windows server 2016

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, windows-server-2016, oracleclient

Oracle client client 12c 32 & 64 bits failling to install on windows server 2016 without printing any error message. When I double click on the installer, it just displays a black window shortly then desepear.

below the log

Using paramFile: C:\win32_12201_client\client32\install\oraparam.ini

Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 4294967296    Passed

The number of files bootstrapped for the jre is 0.

The number of files bootstrapped for the oui is 0.

Comment: Do you need the full client?  Or can you use [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html) which is a simple ZIP install (plus installing a VS Redistributable).

Answer (score 1):

Providing a local file name is rather pointless if you don't provide the content of the file.

You must install with Administrator privileges ("Run as Admin" may not work)

Delete these files/folders before you run the setup:

- `%ProgramFiles%\Oracle\Inventory`
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\Inventory`
- `%TEMP%\deinstall*`
- `%TEMP%\OraInstall*`
- `%TEMP%\CVU*`
- The folder where you like to install the client

Verify your Registry, key `HKLM\Software\Oracle` and `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Oracle` should be deleted

For installation follow this instruction: [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)